# NSURLSession Background task stops while clicking the home button?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have develop a HTTP module for making upload download request using URLSession Background sessions.

The HTTP module work in Serialize mode as specified in URLSession doc by passing nil to queue.

On download complete urlSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:) i do parsing.Based on parsing make request for other file from the same module.

Everything works OK in foreground.

But as i move the application to background by pressing home button downloading and parsing stops.
Because of which i can't able to make another file request in background.
And if application move to foreground downloading will resume.

Can any one help me out for this ?

Comment: Edit your question and show your code!

Comment: Are you using [background session configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background) for lengthy background requests? Or have you simply requested a few minutes to finish your finite length [background task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask)? Bottom line, have you requested background operation of one form or the other and, if so, how did you do that?